# Lookup keys inside a nested hash and then creating a tree of all the keys

Tags: perl, hash

I searched for help how to do this, on google and stackoverflow, and I am now at a point, where I am quite stuck and not able to do this.

I have a heavily nested hash of hashes called BigHash as input and i have a changelist which is also hash which has some keys and values.

I am trying to look for each key in the changelist hash in BigHash, and check if the value matches, and if does not match, then I am trying to create a list of all the ancestors of that key as a string separated by `;`.

Here is my change list and expected output.

## This is my change list :

```
my $changelist = {
'ReqPending' => '9',
'DopplerEnable' => 'true',
'BSColorCode' => '7'
}
```

## This is my expected output :

(Note the output is an array of strings in seperated by commas. Each element in the string is the actual ancestry tree of the key in the changelist concatenated with the value from the changelist for that key.)

```
@Output = "Ctrl;SuperCel;Timers;ReqPending=9", "Phy;CELL;SystemCommon;Config;DopplerEnable=true", "Phy;CELL;SystemCommon;PhysicalCell;BSColorCode=7"
```

## This is my Big Hash :

(The hash is obtained by converting an XML file into a hash, and it has nested arrays and hashes)

```
my $Bighash= {
 'Ctrl' => [
     {
       'SuperCel' => [
                   {
                   'Config' => [
                                        {
                                        'Retry' => '3',
                                        'Context' => '3'
                                        }
                                    ],
                   'Timers' => [
                                        {
                                        'ReqPending' => '2',
                                        'RelocationReqPending' => '2'
                                        }
                                    ]
                   }
            ]
     }
   ],
  'xmlns' => 'http://www.somewebsite.com/oam',
  'Phy' => [
       {
         'CELL' => [
               {
                 'SystemCommon' => [
                      {
                        'Config' => [
                                       {
                                         'SrsOn' => 'true',
                                         'WindowLength' => '2',
                                         'DopplerEnable' => 'false',
                                         'WindowSize' => '3',
                                       }
                                     ],
                        'PhysicalCellID' => '0',
                        'ColorConfig' => [
                                       {
                                         'AckNackFeedback' => '1',
                                         'frameAssignment' => '1',
                                         'SframePattern' => '7'
                                       }
                                     ],
                        'Ports' => '2',
                        'AntennaCount' => '2',
                        'NumberOfConnections' => '8',
                        'PhysicalCell' => [
                                                 {
                                                   'NwColorCode' => '0',
                                                   'BSColorCode' => '0'
                                                 }
                                               ],
                        'CellIdentity' => '0',
                        'IdentityGroup' => '0',
                        'OverrideEnableFlag' => 'false'
                      }
                  ],
                 'Dedicated' => [
                    {
                        'SoundingRs' => [
                            {
                                'ConfigDedicatedRel10' => [
                                    {
                                      'Format' => [
                                           {
                                             'DomainPosition' => '0',
                                             'TransmissionComb' => '0',
                                             'Shift' => '1',
                                             'Port' => '1',
                                             'Bandwidth' => '0'
                                           }
                                        ],
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        'Numerology' => [
                            {
                                'profileNumber' => '0'
                            }
                        ]                                                       
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Can you help me?

I have written something like this, but it is not correct and I am not getting it.

```
sub recursive {
  $hash = shift;

  foreach my $key1 (keys %$hash) {
    if (ref($hash->{$key1}) eq "HASH") {
      if ($var ne "") {
        $var = join(";", $var, $key1);
      }
      else {
        $var = $key1;
      }
      recursive($hash->{$key1});
    }
    elsif (ref($hash->{$key1}) eq "ARRAY") {
      $tem = @{ $hash->{$key1} };
      if ($var ne "") {
        $var = join(";", $var, $key1);
      }
      else {
        $var = $key1;
      }
      foreach $item (@{ $hash->{$key1} }) {
        if (ref($item) eq "HASH") {
          #$var = join (";",$var,$key1);
          recursive($item);
        }
        else {
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      if ($var ne "") {
        $temp = $var;
        $var = join(";", $var, $key1);
        print $var. "\n";
        #$var=$temp;
      }
      else {
        $var = $key1;
        undef($var);
      }
    }
  }
}

recursive($BigHash);
```

Comment: In your `$Bighash`, why is each hash ref embedded in an array ref?  Does this have to do with how the bighash is being generated?  Was this originally XML or some other format, and you used a module like `XML::Simple` to get this structure, and you're actually trying to edit the XML?  Are you certain this is all the relevant information, and that this isn't an [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Yes, I got this `$BigHash` by converting an XML file into a hash., that is why it is like that :(

Comment: Is your final goal to edit the XML file itself with these updated values?  Note [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) is outdated, although it does have options to get you better output.  The best option however is to use a module like [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML).  If you shared your actual data and goal with us, you'd likely get some much better advice.

Comment: No, I have an API that will make me a new XML file if I send that output string, it is hard to edit the XMLfile as it has to adhere to a very strict schema in the xsd file, and the hash converted back to XML is not as per the schema, so I devised a new way of updating my XML file.

Comment: Looking back, I see you've done multiple questions concerning `XML::Simple`.  I advise you that it's time for you to explore other solutions instead of being stuck on this Y of this [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/256831).  My advice is that you start a new question where you list the XML that you're working with and what you're trying to do to it.  You can even reference back to this problem stating that you've been working with `XML::Simple` but that you're open to other solutions.

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo: I encourage you to take notice of what Miller is saying. I know it is a big decision to backtrack over a number of design choices that you have spent a lot of work on, but your initial problems were because you chose `XML::Simple` in the first place. It is a dreadful module for producing reliable output, and your *"new way of updating [your] XML file"* is all because of this failing. If you use `XML::LibXML` instead, then the process is very straightforward. Look at Ikegami's post to see how simple it could be: it really is that easy!

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo I also got started with `XML::Simple`, but eventually moved to `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML`.  It took a while to learn both, but it took a lot less time than trying to get `XML::Simple` to do jobs it wasn't designed for.  For a tutorial, check out: [`Stepping up from XML::Simple to XML::LibXML`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=490846)

Comment: Cool, you and #Borodin and #ikegami has convinced me to move to LibXML. I was struggling to find a good tutorial and also mentally battling having to re-write everything I did so far, but I decided to go back and start from the beginning. Thanks for all the help and for the tutorial. Its nicely written.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub find_missing_changes {
   my $changelist = shift;
   my @output;

   local *_helper = sub {
      my $data = pop;

      my $reftype = ref($data)
         or return;

      if ($reftype eq 'ARRAY') {
         for my $i (0..$#$data) {
            _helper(@_, $i, $data->[$i]);
         }
      }

      elsif ($reftype eq 'HASH') {
         for my $k (keys(%$data)) {
            if (exists($changelist->{$k}) && $data->{$k} ne $changelist->{$k}) {
               push @output, join(';', @_, $k)."=".$changelist->{$k};
            }

            _helper(@_, $k, $data->{$k});
         }
      }
   };

   _helper(@_);

   return @output;
}

print "$_\n" for find_missing_changes($changelist, $Bighash);
```

Output:

```
Phy;0;CELL;0;SystemCommon;0;Config;0;DopplerEnable=true
Phy;0;CELL;0;SystemCommon;0;PhysicalCell;0;BSColorCode=7
Ctrl;0;SuperCel;0;Timers;0;ReqPending=9
```

If you don't need the array indexes, you shouldn't tell `XMLin` that there can be more than one occurrences of those elements.

Comment: Hmm. I see a `0` between `Phy` and `CELL` I was trying to get my ancestry as a list of strings. Like this : `"Phy;CELL;SystemCommon;DopplerEnable=true","Ctrl;SuperCel;Timers;ReqPending=9"`

Comment: Then you won't have sufficient information to know which element needs fixing, unless you're saying there can be only one of each of those elements, in which case the fault is yours for including too much in `ForceArray`. Fix the incorrect `ForceArray` to make the "problem" goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This parses the XML file, performs the changes in `%$changelist`, and saves the changes:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new( no_network => 1 );
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($qfn);

for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//*')) {
   for my $attr_name (keys(%$changelist)) {
      if ($node->hasAttribute($attr_name)) {
         $node->setAttribute($changelist->{$attr_name});
      }
   }
}

$doc->toFile($qfn);
```

Comment: ah, installing that module and trying it out now, let me update you.